# Calculating sample size for reducing standard error

Tags: sample-size, standard-error

How to calculate a suitable sample size for reducing the standard error by a factor of 4? For instance if I have sample size of 1000 how much would I increase it to have a standard error reduced by 4?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! How are you calculating the standard error? If you have an equation, perhaps that can suggest a solution.

Comment: I don't have more data. Standard error of the estimate mean should be equal to σ / √n

Comment: So if you want $\sigma/\sqrt n$ to be a quarter of its previous size, what do you have to do to $n?$

Answer (score 0):

$$
SE_1 =\dfrac{\sigma}{\sqrt n_1}\\
SE_2 =\dfrac{\sigma}{\sqrt n_2}
$$

You want $SE_1/SE_2=4$. Therefore, $
4=SE_1/SE_2=\dfrac{
\sigma/\sqrt{n_1}
}{
\sigma/\sqrt{n_2}
}
$. Now just do some algebra to get $n_2$ in terms of $n_1$.